# How do I import images using the module migrate source CSV?

Tags: media, importing-exporting

I'm using the module migrate source csv to import a csv file.
I took a look at the page https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/modules/migrate-source-csv/using-the-migra... to understand how to use the module.
This is my CSV file.

```
id,title,body, field_image
1,title 1,some body text 1, image_from_the_web.jpg
2,title 2,some body text 2, image_from_the_web.jpg
3,title 3,some body text 3, image_from_the_web.jpg
```

This is my configuration.

```
id: basuuid 
label: Import articles
migration_groups:
  - ACME import

source:
  plugin: csv
  # Full path to the file.
  path: '/mypath/to/file/acme_articles.csv'
  # Column delimiter. Comma (,) by default.
  delimiter: ','
  # Field enclosure. Double quotation marks (") by default.
  enclosure: '"'
  # The number of rows at the beginning which are not data.
  header_row_count: 1
  keys:
    - id
  # Here we identify the columns of interest in the source file. 
  # Each numeric key is the 0-based index of the column. 
  # For each column, the key below is the field name assigned to 
  # the data on import, to be used in field mappings below. 
  # The value is a user-friendly string for display by the 
  # migration UI.
  column_names:
    0:
      id: 'Unique Id'
    1:
      title: 'Title'
    2:
      body: 'Post body'
    3:
     field_image: 'Image'
process:
  title: title
  body: body
  field_image:  field_image
  type:
    plugin: default_value
    default_value: article

destination:
  plugin: entity:node
```

When I want to execute `drush migrate-import basuuid`, I get this error:

> Call to a member function getFileUri() on a non-object in /drupal/core/modules/image/src/Plugin/Field/FieldType/ImageItem.php

I took a look on other topics to solve my problem, without success.

How do I migrate images?

Thank you

Comment: Sounds like it can't find the file?

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a separate yml for the image config. There's a tutorial here: https://www.mtech-llc.com/blog/ada-hernandez/how-migrate-images-drupal-8-using-csv-source